# How to iterate and assign values of List object internally when Iterating over Map in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, hashmap

```
public List<ErrorMessage> getErrorMessageDetails(ValidationResult validationResult, String severity) {

        Map<List<String>, List<String>> errorObjectsMap = new HashMap<>();

       //errorCode= some values in List of strings
       //errorMessage= some values in List of strings

        errorObjectsMap.put(errorCode, errorMessage);

        List<ErrorMessage> errorMessageList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<List<String>, List<String>> pair : errorObjectsMap.entrySet()) {
            List<String> errorCodeMsg = pair.getKey() == null ? new ArrayList<>() : pair.getKey();
            List<String> errorMsg = pair.getValue() == null ? new ArrayList<>() : pair.getValue();

            errorMessageList.add(new ErrorMessage(errorCodeMsg.get(0), errorMsg.get(0)));

// So in above line of code i want to iterate both list k,v and use its keys and values to create list of List<ErrorMessage> errorMessageList dynamically without using index of lists

        }
        return errorMessageList;
    }
```

Please refer above java method to suggestions.

Could someone please help to write logic to iterate dynamically in most concise way in java?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presented method does not use any of the input arguments `validationResult` and `severity` and it shows that the map contains only one entry.

However, to simply build a list of error messages, Stream API could be used to convert the stream of map entries into the list of `ErrorMessage` where the lists in map entries are iterated by indexes provided by `IntStream` and `flatMap` is applied to join the error messages from all entries:

```java
public List<ErrorMessage> getErrorMessageDetails(ValidationResult validationResult, String severity) {

    Map<List<String>, List<String>> errorObjectsMap = new HashMap<>();

    //errorCode= some values in List of strings
    //errorMessage= some values in List of strings

    errorObjectsMap.put(errorCode, errorMessage);
    // assuming there are more entries

    return errorObjectsMap.entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<List<String>, List<String>>>
        .filter(e -> e.getKey() != null && e.getValue() != null
            && !e.getKey().isEmpty() && !e.getValue().isEmpty()
        )
        .flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, Math.min(e.getKey().size(), e.getValue().size()))
                .mapToObj(i -> new ErrorMessage(
                    e.getKey().get(i), e.getValue().get(i)
                )) // Stream<ErrorMessage>
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```